# How to do Automated UI testing for Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have an actionscript 2 application that I'd like to write automated UI testing for.
For example I'd like to simulate a mouse click on a button and validate that a movie-clip is displayed at the right position and in the right color... Basically, UI testing.
What are the best tools available or what is the desired approach?
In JavaScript there is the selenium framework which does a nice job. Any similar tool for flash?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but this could be useful for future reference. There is a relatively new project

[Automated UI tester for ActionScript](https://sourceforge.net/adobe/genie/wiki/Home/)

Its installation is pretty simple, and is described in the user guide step by step.

Answer (score 4):

Use Adobe genie (UI Tester for ActionScript)
http://sourceforge.net/adobe/genie/discussion/general/

But I don't think AS1 or AS2 will work. It works only with AS3.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use any HTML/JS autotesting tool and provide a JS api to your Flash app - at least, you can always expose functions like 'locate smth by id', 'click smth by id', 'enter some text into smth by id' or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://SauceLabs.com - they've got a Flash and Flex testing tool

Answer (score 0):

This may be of use

[Flash UI testing](http://osflash.org/autotestflash)

Comment: Unfortunately most of the links on the page you referred to are broken :-(
Reading the doc, however this doesn't look like the ideal solution for me. I'm looking for a way to test UI but with no manual procedure involved. Just write (ideally AS) code that tests UI

Comment: And the Test link is virus-infected.