# Script an interaction with a website that uses flash?

Tags: flash, webautomation

I would like to write a script that interacts with a web service which does not provide an API, through it's public website.  (To the best of my knowledge, this would not be a violation of the TOS for the site in question.)

The catch is that the site's UI is written in Flash, so it's not as simple as using curl or something similar.

Are there any tools, libaries, or tips that let me script interaction with flash in a dynamic way, on my PC (rather than a hosted solution)?  I expect that this would be similar to a testing framework...

Comment: You might look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126573/how-to-do-automated-ui-testing-for-flash) (about testing flash UI) for some ideas...

Comment: Their flash content will be getting data from their Use HTTPFox and examine what data it is loading at run time and just snag that data. Of course if you use flashto do it you are limited to the cross domain policy on that site or you can curl the data